# How can I edit a symbol in context in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

In Sketch, I have two symbols that lock together like puzzle pieces.  If I want to modify one, it takes me to an isolated view where I can no longer tell if my modifications are going over the bounds of the other sister symbol.

How can I modify a symbol in the context it's meant to be used?

Comment: Hi Seph, did my answer help you? If so, would you mind accepting it? Here's how: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I correct to assume you didn't move your symbols to the "symbols" page? I suggest you do that, and you should be fine:

- If one of your symbols contains the other, modifying the contained one will show the update in the containing one immediately
- If they both are part of a whole, I suggest you create an additional symbol that contains them both, move all three to the symbols page and edit there. Once done, you can still delete the symbol that contains the two others (or simply not use it).

Hope that helps!